# Create a dictionary from a list of key and multi list of values in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of key:

```
list_date = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU","FRI"]
```

I have many lists of values that created by codes below:

```
list_value = list()
for i in list(range(5, 70, 14)):
    list_value.append(list(range(i, i+10, 3)))
```

Rules created that:

- first number is 5, a list contains 4 items has value equal x = x + 3, and so on [5, 8, 11,1 4]
- the first number of the second list equal: x = 5 + 14, and value inside still as above x = x +3

  [[5, 8, 11, 14], [19, 22, 25, 28], [33, 36, 39, 42], [47, 50, 53, 56], [61, 64, 67, 70]]

I expect to obtain a dict like this:

```
collections = {"MON":[5, 8, 11, 14], "TUE" :[19, 22, 25, 28], "WED":[33, 36, 39, 42], "THU":[47, 50, 53, 56], "FRI":[61, 64, 67, 70]}
```

Then, I used:

```
zip_iterator = zip(list_date, list_value)
collections = dict(zip_iterator)
```

To get my expected result.

I tried another way like using `lambda` function

```
for i in list(range(5, 70, 14)):
    list_value.append(list(range(i,i+10,3)))
    couple_start_end[lambda x: x in list_date] = list(range(i, i + 10, 3))
```

And the output is:

```
{<function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0711F0>: [5, 8, 11, 14], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F071310>: [19, 22, 25, 28], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F071280>: [33, 36, 39, 42], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0710D0>: [47, 50, 53, 56], <function <lambda> at 0x000001BF7F0890D0>: [61, 64, 67, 70]}
```

I want to ask there is any better solution to create lists of values with the rules above? and create the dictionary `collections` without using the `zip` method?

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: Questions seeking to optimize working code might be a better fit for [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/). Remember to check their [on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [asking guidelines](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use `enumerate` but I wouldn't say it is in anyway better or worse than the `zip` based solution:

```
collections = {}
for idx, key in enumerate(list_keys):
    collections[key] = list_value[idx]
print(collections)
```

Output:

```
{'MON': [5, 8, 11, 14], 'TUE': [19, 22, 25, 28], 'WED': [33, 36, 39, 42], 'THU': [47, 50, 53, 56], 'FRI': [61, 64, 67, 70]}
```

Further, you don't need to create the value list separately, you can create the dictionary as you go along:

```
list_keys = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU","FRI"]
collections = {}
for idx, start in enumerate(range(5, 70, 14)):
    collections[list_keys[idx]] = [i for i in range(start, start+10, 3)]
print(collections)
```